# How do I get a complete list of all Windows AD computer accounts that are part of a cluster group in my AD domain?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, failovercluster, windows-cluster, microsoft-cluster-server

Regardless of whether they are active nodes or passive nodes, how do we get a list of all Windows AD computer accounts in a cluster group?

Using the PowerShell module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/?view=windowsserver2022-ps this can only show the Active cluster node.

Using the below Command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { (ServicePrincipalNames -like '*Cluster*') } -Properties 'OperatingSystem', 'ServicePrincipalNames'
```

Can only show the Cluster Group Name

Any comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like `Get-ClusterGroup "ClusterGroupA" | Get-ClusterNode` as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clustergroup?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-2 but you'd need to build your group list with your logic in the post, and then loop that into the example command as I listed. I don't have a cluster to test this on or I would and write an answer, but if helpful, I can still help and put in an answer if you tell me to loop over a list you get when you run your query, let me know.

Comment: Hi @PimpJuiceIT, yes, that does make sense. thank you for the help and pointer in this case.